# Is there a way to set variables as an escape character using set /p?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to catch escape characters like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and so on.
When we press these escape combination, the prompt shows `^Z` `^A`, but when I try to use them as a value to a variable, the code doesn't works.

```
set /p "input=> "
echo/%input%
```

The above code shows as output just `%input%` when I put an escape character, the variable is empty.
So, is there a way to catch them? Or this isn't possible?

Comment: Another input program from a third party can help with capturing more input combinations.  Ask for help on http://www.dostips.com forum as a couple were written and posted there in about the last two weeks.

Comment: I would enjoy knowing an answer to this as it would help with setting variables from user input containing special characters requiring escapes (especially with '%' and '!').

Comment: @foxidrive it is possible to do what the OP is asking for in this specific case without any third part software.

Comment: @monacraft In a straightforward way, no I don't think so.  You may be able to use a VBS script etc.

Comment: @monacraft Your answer isn't getting the keystrokes as input, which the question is asking for AIUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch these keys you need an external program of you could write your own key input with missusing `XCOPY`.

This can catch nearly all characters, but not the cursor keys or F1..F12

```
@echo off

:loop
set "key="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`xcopy /L /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>NUL`) do (
  if not defined key set "key=%%L"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "key=!key:~-1!"
echo '!key!'
endlocal
goto :loop
```

Comment: Perfect @jeb, this worked like a charm.
I had to make  a conditional operation to catch the correct combination, as Monacraft said on his answer, I had to write the combination in a temporary text file, then I had to do it again with the text file content, so, with result I could compare using IF statement. Thanks all that helped me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `^A`, `^B`, `^G` and a whole other bunch of letters (where the `^` is achieved with `ctrl+letter`). Note it is not possible with `^Z` and `^C` or atleast not with this method.

I was in a very similar situation to you when I needed to output sound in one of my batch programs. You do this through a temp text file:

```
C:\> Echo ^A > tmp.txt
C:\> set /p ctrl_A=<tmp.txt
C:\> Echo ^G > tmp.txt
C:\> set /p ctrl_G=<tmp.txt
C:\> del tmp.txt
C:\> Echo %ctrl_A%
☺

C:\> Echo %ctrl_G%


C:\> Rem In above double blank you should hear a beep from your computer.
```

This is how I made use of sound in my program. Note, everytime you see a `^` in the code remember to `ctrl+letter`.

Now to use this in batch files you need to utilise Notepad.

1. In cmd type `Echo ^G > tmp.txt`
2. Then type `Notepad tmp.txt`
3. In the notepad window select everything in the first line, sometimes it will be a large dot, others it will just be four consecutive spaces. Copy it anyhow(make sure not to leave anything)
4. Close Notepad, type `del tmp.txt` and exit cmd
5. At the start of your batch file set the variable to whatever is on the clipboard

And voila you can use these speacial features in CMD and in BATCH!

Hope this helped, Mona.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code

```
set /p "input=> "
echo/%input%
```

seems to work if there is at least one character after the Code (may also be a space) (for example try to input `Hello^G World` (using Ctrl-G to produce `^G`). It produces "Hello World" plus a beep.

`Hello World^G` doesn't work, `Hello World^G<space>` does.